# R Feature Selection with caret - Limit results plot to top 10 and also store full results into data frame

Tags: r, plot, r-caret, feature-selection

I am relatively new to R and trying my hand at feature selection for the first time. I followed a tutorial online that used the PimaIndiansDiabetes dataset as an example. I repeated the steps in this tutorial on my own dataset that has over 110 features.

I have included the sample code for the tutorial I used below. The only difference is that my code has a larger dataset and different naming conventions.

When I plot the importance value for my own results the plot has over 110 items appearing. Does anybody know how I can limit this to the top 10?

```
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
# ensure results are repeatable
set.seed(7)

# load the dataset
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes)

# prepare training scheme
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)

# train the model
model <- train(diabetes~., data=PimaIndiansDiabetes, method="lvq", 
preProcess="scale", trControl=control)

# estimate variable importance
importance <- varImp(model, scale=FALSE)

# summarize importance

print(importance)

# plot importance
plot(importance)
```

I also want to be able to store these full results into a dataframe.
I tried the following command:

```
importanceDF <- as.data.frame(importance)
```

but I get the following error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(importance) : 
    cannot coerce class ""varImp.train"" to a data.frame
```

Apologies if this is a simple question, I have tried googling but have yet to find an answer that works.

Thanks in advance,

Amy

EDIT:

As per zacdav's answer I have applied the following logic:

```
importance$importance
temp <- importance
temp$importance <- importance$importance[1:5, ]
plot(temp)
```

However I noted that when I original run
     plot(importance)

The order is as follows in the sample data:

```
             Importance
glucose      0.7881
mass         0.6876
age          0.6869
pregnant     0.6195
pedigree     0.6062
pressure     0.5865
triceps      0.5536
insulin      0.5379
```

Then when I run
    temp$importance <- importance$importance[1:5, ]
    plot(temp)

I get the following order:

```
glucose
pregnant
pressure
triceps
insulin
```

This is taking the top 5 rows in how they appear n the original table rather than based on their importance.

I tried running the following:

```
# put into DF
 importanceDF <- importance$importance
# sort
importanceDF_Ordered <- importanceDF[order(-importanceDF$neg),] 
temp <- importanceDF_Ordered
```

The last line then gives an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "importance", value = list(neg = 
 c(0.619514925373134,  : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 8
```

- have no idea how to fix this so any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the structure of the importance object you will see it is a list comprising of three elements, a data.frame of the importance values towards each response class and other metadata. You can just index the data.frame using the `$` notation.

```
str(importance)

List of 3
 $ importance:'data.frame': 8 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ neg: num [1:8] 0.62 0.788 0.586 0.554 0.538 ...
  ..$ pos: num [1:8] 0.62 0.788 0.586 0.554 0.538 ...
 $ model     : chr "ROC curve"
 $ calledFrom: chr "varImp"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "varImp.train"
```

So to get the data.frame all you need to do is `importance$importance`

As far as adjusting this object so you can plot a subset of the features you can adjust the object. I would suggest maybe making a copy so that analysis does not need to be rerun. A crude example is as follows:

```
temp <- importance
temp$importance <- importance$importance[1:5, ]
plot(temp)
```

I have chosen to plot the first five using `1:5` row index on the data.frame to override the temp objects data.frame.
If you are interested in calling the plot method directly use `caret:::plot.varImp.train`

Comment: Thank you so much for you help really appreciate it.

Comment: thanks for your help, however I noticed that when I run the command plot(temp) it does not actually plot it in order. Rather it takes the rows as ho they appear originally and not by importance. I have edited my question to include code I tried using to fix this issue, would you mind looking  to see if you know where I am going wrong please

Answer (score 3):

plot has a built in argument for taking the top x number of values

```
plot(importance, top=10)
```